# Perform action client-side when TFS work item is saved in VS 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tfs, event-handling

Goal: Capture the event raised when a TFS work item is saved in the Visual Studio UI, and prompt the user to send a boilerplate email to the person that the item is assigned to.

Issue: I'm unable to ascertain how to go about doing this. I've started a VS extension project, as that seemed like the most promising route, but from there I don't know where to look for the the window I need, or how to reliably subscribe to the saving event when such a window is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to write a Visual Studio extension to create that type of functionality.  Its not impossible but also not for the faint of heart. :)

It seems like your use case may be better served by TFS Notifications?

[Set alerts, get notified when changes occur](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181334%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

UPDATE:

Another option may be to use TFS events via a web service, which looks much easier than a VS extensions - http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/08/02/How-to-use-WCF-to-subscribe-to-the-TFS-2010-Event-Service-rolling-up-hours.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, we appear to be running an older TFS version and don't have the option to set up custom alerts. The VS extension seems like the way to go, I just can't seem to find out how to do what I'm trying to do with it.

Comment: Notifications go all the way back to TFS 2010.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181334(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yes, but _custom_ alerts do not. The options for 2010 are [limited to these few](http://i.imgur.com/TdsuySy.png), which aren't suitable for my objective.

Comment: Gotcha.  I wrote a VERY basic VS extension which may serve as a decent example for you.  Here is a summary, also see the GitHub link at the bottom of the post - https://dotnetcatch.wordpress.com/2014/09/08/parameterizationpreview-visual-studio-extension/

Comment: Thanks. Selecting this as the answer because I can't seem to find any documentation or examples of how to access the TFS portion of Visual Studio with the extension framework, and the web service solution performs the desired function.

Comment: @chief7 Sorry I fail to view where in this extension are you detecting WorkItem saved events. Care to clarify?